# How to make layout fill everything inside qt tab widget?

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I added a tab widget in my Qt application, and then added a vertical layout in the first tab, and added things inside the vertical layout. However, I cannot make the vertical layout fill the entire tab, I can only set the dimensions with the mouse. There's no option to make it fill everything.

[image]

How to make a vertical layout (or any widget) fill the entire widget tab?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a layout to each tab. In Creator, look for the layout in the widget hierarchy!

[image]

Comment: In the case where I haven't any, what should I do then? If I just create a new layout inside, it won't automatically fill the tab page like @guerlando-ocs said.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the same issue and found the solution.

Scenario:

- I have an existing QTabWidget
- I create new tab using: right-click on last tab -> Insert Page -> After..
- The new tab shows the icon saying it doesn't have a layout
- Drag-and-drop a layout from the left panel inside the new tab

Now that you have put a layout inside, even if it's not filling the tab, you right-click on the tab and select "Layout" -> "Layout vertically" (for example), and then boom, it will fill the tab.